# Is there any way to dynamically add a CSS class selector to a view with submitted exposed filters?

Tags: views

I need to add some different styling to a view based on whether the exposed filters have been applied or not. Eg add the class "filtered" once a person has submitted their info in the exposed filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with View's pre_render hook, eg, something along the lines of this:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name=='NAME_OF_YOUR_VIEW') {
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . $view->exposed_data . '</pre>'); // to see what you have to work with
    if (!empty($view->exposed_data['type'])) { 
      $view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', 'view-has-been-filtered');
    }
  }

}
```

The above is based on a node type exposed filter, you will need to look at your View to see what filter names are involved, but the logic is that the exposed_data filter arrays will be empty until you have applied the filter.  For example, here, this looks like this when you first go to the View:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
        )

    [submit] => Apply
    [form_build_id] => form-85a47ba22bc12a8b443e4cc35afe75f7
    [form_token] => 105c57eec73efe4cfedd9acabc55786a
    [form_id] => views_exposed_form
    [] => Apply
)
```

and this is what it looks like after selecting 'foo' as a type in the exposed filter:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [foo] => foo
        )

    [submit] => Apply
    [form_build_id] => form-85a47ba22bc12a8b443e4cc35afe75f7
    [form_token] => 105c57eec73efe4cfedd9acabc55786a
    [form_id] => views_exposed_form
    [] => Apply
)
```

ADDITION:

If this works for you, and per your comment, I suppose the following would work for any/all Views, but I haven't battle tested it...

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  $filter_classes=array('view-has-been-filtered');

  if (!empty($view->exposed_data) && is_array($view->exposed_data)) {

    foreach($view->exposed_data as $k => $key) {
      if (is_array($key) && !empty($key)) {
        $filter_classes[]='view-has-been-filtered-by-' . str_replace('_', '-', $k);
      }
    }

    if (count($filter_classes) > 1) {
      $view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', implode(' ', $filter_classes));
    }

  }

}
```

...with the logic here being the only arrays in `$view->exposed_data` are filters, and if they aren't empty, the View has been filtered.

EEEK ADDITION:

My logic is somewhat flawed in that my initial tests were for filters that allowed multiple selections, and, of course, Views used arrays to capture them in `$view->exposed_data`.  If your filters are just single value fields, Views will do something like this first:

```
Array
(
    [multiple_value_allowed_type] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_single_value_field] => All
    [submit] => Apply
    [form_build_id] => form-f601bde36c625db96bad7a84bf4fa210
    [form_token] => 105c57eec73efe4cfedd9acabc55786a
    [form_id] => views_exposed_form
    [] => Apply
)
```

so I guess the following dull ax approach would work:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  $filter_classes=array('view-has-been-filtered');

  if (!empty($view->exposed_data) && is_array($view->exposed_data)) {

    foreach($view->exposed_data as $k => $key) {
      if (is_array($key)) {
        if (!empty($key)) {
          $filter_classes[]='view-has-been-filtered-by-' . str_replace('_', '-', $k);
        }
      } else {
        switch ($k) {
          case 'submit':
          case 'form_build_id':
          case 'form_token':
          case 'form_id':
            break;
          default:
            if (!empty($k) && $key != 'All')  {
              $filter_classes[]='view-has-been-filtered-by-' . str_replace('_', '-', $k);
            }
        }
      }
    }

    if (count($filter_classes) > 1) {
      $view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', implode(' ', $filter_classes));
    }

  }

}
```

DOUBLE D'OH ADDITION:

Of course, this quick and dirty logic also works:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if (!empty($view->exposed_data) && count($_GET) > 1) {
    $view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', 'view-has-been-filtered');
  }

}
```

ADDITION DUE TO COMMENTARY:

If you are setting css classes via the UI that you want to preserve, you can do this:

```
$view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class') . ' view-has-been-filtered');
```

which gets that UI option and then adds the `view-has-been-filtered` class to it.  Please note the required space in front in the code :)

Comment: Thanks, Jimajamma. I will give this a shot. Any way to modify this so it applies to any and all views in general?

Comment: Sorry to poke at this again. If you have some time, is there a way to do this using the theme layer? I'll throw another 100 point bounty on the question if it's something worth your while.

Comment: by theme layer, do you mean from a `MYTHEME_hook()` function implemented inside of your theme's `template.php` file?  If so, you can put a `YOURTHEME_views_pre_render()` function in there with the same logic as above and it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Great. That sort of works. The "quick and dirt logic one" but it appears to remove any extra added classes that I have set in the views UI. Any way to keep my custom classes set in the UI as well?

Comment: I've added in some addition code in the answer above that should address this.  Good call.  Basically you call the handler's `get_option()` function and then append the class to it.  (This is a space delimited list of classes)

Answer (score -2):

To any view,you can add a different css class by
1. First clicking on the editing option on a view
2. In the Page details,click on ADVANCED properties
3. Add the **css** class to the second last attribute present there which is css class.
This way you can add css classes to every view.

Comment: I need the class to only be added when a view is in a filtered state so that I can apply different styling.