# How do I display different "No results behavior" based on exposed filter results and total results?

Tags: 7, views

e.g. A view for job postings has an exposed filter to search by title.

1. I want to show a "No results behavior" if there aren't any jobs at all `"There are no postings at this time. Please check back later."`
2. I also want to show different text if their search returned no results, but there are still postings available. It's just their search didn't match anything. `"Sorry, there are no results matching your search criteria."`

It appears that I can only do one or the other.

Comment: are you using D6 or D7 ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score 4):

You could easily adapt the `views-view.tpl.php` to your specific view, eg, `views-view--VIEWNAME.tpl.php` and change up the portion dealing with no results...

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
  <div class="view-content">
    <?php print $rows; ?>
  </div>
<?php elseif ($empty): ?>
  <div class="view-empty">
    <?php print $empty; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...with something along the lines of...

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
  <div class="view-content">
    <?php print $rows; ?>
  </div>
<?php elseif ($empty): ?>
  <div class="view-empty">
    <?php if (count($_GET)>1): ?>
      Sorry, there are no results matching your search criteria.  Perhaps with other filters you may find some.
    <?php else: ?>
      There are no postings at this time. Please check back later.
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...with just some really simple logic based upon parameters Views uses for the exposed filters (eg, if more than `?q=PATH` is sent it will have more than just 1 in `$_GET`).

Now if you want to get fancier than this you may want to investigate one of the Views preprocess hooks and actually change up the `$empty` variable and not put a lot of logic in the template.

If that's the case you could go further and re-run the View via [views_get_view_result()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) without any filters and if it had any results, actually return your desired `Sorry, there are no results matching your search criteria.`  (You could do this in this template file but I really try to keep lots of deep logic outside of them)

([Is there any way to dynamically add a CSS class selector to a view with submitted exposed filters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74579/is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-add-a-css-class-selector-to-a-view-with-submitte/74954#74954) has some more code you might be able to re-use here as well)

Answer (score 0):

Snippet code to display different "No results behaviour" based on exposed filter results and total results:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view__HOOK() for job posting view.
 */
function nkf_preprocess_views_view__job_posting(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    $result_count = $view->total_rows;
    $exposedInput = $view->getExposedInput();
    // Set the no result behaviour if job_type filter selected.
    if (!empty($exposedInput['job_type']) && $result_count == null) {
      $variables['empty'] = t('There are no postings at this time. Please check back later.');
    }
    elseif ($result_count == null) {
      // Set the no result behaviour if job_type filter not selected.
      $variables['empty'] = t('Sorry, there are no results matching your search criteria.');
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**
job_posting denotes the machine name of view, nkf denotes either module or theme name depends upon working in .module/.theme file

**Informative tips:**
The solution of this problem to use:
`hook_preprocess_views_view__HOOK()` instead of using `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter()`

Earlier I was trying to use `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter` however I wasn't able to update the no result behaviour then came to know major basic difference between them and reach to solution.

**hook_preprocess_views_view__HOOK**: This hook 'll be use to alter the view variables (for eg: no result behaviour variable) before rendering view.

**hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter**: This hook 'll be use to alter form definition/elements (for eg: alter exposed filter) before executing view.